# How to pass variable to controller from a directive which is outside of controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to get some attributes which are set in ng-view div (outside of main controller scope). Using custom directive to pass the attribute values is the solution I guess.. So I have:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <!--Load ng-view and add attrs-->
    <div ng-view 
         my-directive 
         first-attr="attrOne" 
         second-attr="attrSecond">
    </div>
</body>
```

directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link:link,
        scope: {
            firstVal: '=firstAttr',
            secondVal: '=secondAttr'
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

app settings and controller:

```
angular
    .module('myapp', [
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/myApp');
        $stateProvider
            .state('myApp', {
                url: '/myApp',
                templateUrl: 'main.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            });

    });

.controller(mainCtrl, mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl ($scope) {

}
```

Is it possible to get those attribute values in main controller as the page is loaded?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you missed to explain where/how your mainCtrl is used

Comment: @alfrescian I added ui-router settings that show how/where mainCtrl is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a parent child relationship between the 'mainController' and the directive.

You can use event emitter

directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link:link,
        controller:controller
        scope: {
            firstVal: '=firstAttr',
            secondVal: '=secondAttr'
        }
    }
    return directive;

    function controller($scope){
        //SOME LOGIC
        $scope.firstVal = "firstVal LOGIC"
        $scope.secondVal = "secondVal LOGIC"

        //EMIT AFTER LOGIC DONE
        var data = { firstVal: $scope.firstVal, secondVal: $scope.secondVal};
        $scope.$emit('YOUR_CONTROLLER_EVENT', data);
    }
}
```

controller:

```
.controller(mainCtrl, mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('YOUR_CONTROLLER_EVENT', function(event, data){
        var firstVal = data.firstVal;
        var secondVal = data.secondVal;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your solution implies there is a parent-child relation present and would break as soon as the directive is being placed somewhere outside this relationship, therefore I wouldn't really recommend this solution.

Comment: He named the controller 'mainController' that is why  I assumed that there is a parent child relationship. But I'll edit my answer anyway. Thanks.